# How do I select IDs using xpath in Nokogiri?

Tags: ruby, xpath, nokogiri

Using this code:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("text.html"))
doc.xpath("//span[@id='startsWith_']").remove
```

I would like to select every `span#id` starting with `'startsWith_'` and remove it. I tried searching, but failed.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example:

```
require 'nokogiri'

html = '
<html>
<body>
  <span id="doesnt_start_with">foo</span>
  <span id="startsWith_bar">bar</span>
</body>
</html>'

doc = Nokogiri::HTML(html)
p doc.search('//span[starts-with(@id, "startsWith_")]').to_xml
```

That's how to select them.

```
doc.search('//span[starts-with(@id, "startsWith_")]').each do |n|
  n.remove
end
```

That's how to remove them.

```
p doc.to_xml
# >> "<span id=\"startsWith_bar\">bar</span>"
# >> "<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd\">\n<html><body>\n  <span id=\"doesnt_start_with\">foo</span>\n  \n</body></html>\n"
```

The page "[XPath, XQuery, and XSLT Functions](http://www.w3schools.com/Xpath/xpath_functions.asp)" has a list of the available functions.

Comment: do you know why some functions does not works (for instance - ends-with())?

Comment: I don't know. Nokogiri uses libxml2, which is a standard XML parser. You should ask that on the Nokogiri-talk mail list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath expression:

```
//span[starts-with(@id, 'startsWith_')]
```